# Kafka set up 2 authentications SASL_PLAINTEXT and SASL_SSL

Tags: apache-kafka

I intended to setup 2 authentication modes which are SASL_PLAINTEXT and SASL_SSL. SASL_PLAINTEXT will be used between brokers and zookeeper, and SASL_SSL will be used with external producers and consumers.
I can completely set either one of them, but can't set them both at the same time.
Now Broker can authenticate with Zookeeper, but I can't have Producer to authenticate to Broker via SASL_SSL:9093.

Server.properties

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://172.22.10.21:9092,SASL_SSL://172.22.10.21:9093
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://172.22.10.21:9092,SASL_SSL://172.22.10.21:9093
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.truststore.location=/home/aaapi/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=serversecret
ssl.keystore.location=/home/aaapi/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=serversecret
ssl.key.password=serversecret
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256,SCRAM-SHA-512,PLAIN
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512 here
```

server_jaas.conf

```
sasl_ssl.KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="adminssl"
    password="adminssl-secret";
};
sasl_plaintext.KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret"
   user_admin="admin-secret"
   user_kafkabroker1="kafkabroker1-secret";
};
Client {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="admin-secret";
};
```

zookeeper_jaas.conf

```
Server {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

client_ssl.properties

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
#bootstrap.servers=172.22.10.21:9093
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.truststore.location=/home/aaapi/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=clientsecret
ssl.keystore.location=/home/aaapi/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=serversecret
ssl.key.password=serversecret
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
  username="adminssl" \
  password="adminssl-secret";
```

Error

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 172.22.10.21:9093 --topic test1 --producer.config /home/aaapi/client_config/consumer/client_ssl.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/kafka-3.2.1-src/tools/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/kafka-3.2.1-src/trogdor/build/dependant-libs-2.13.6/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/kafka-3.2.1-src/connect/runtime/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/kafka-3.2.1-src/connect/mirror/build/dependant-libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
>[2022-11-11 19:45:06,787] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (ip-172-22-10-21.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/172.22.10.21:9093) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:06,788] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 172.22.10.21:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:07,388] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (ip-172-22-10-21.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/172.22.10.21:9093) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:07,388] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 172.22.10.21:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:08,323] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (ip-172-22-10-21.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/172.22.10.21:9093) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:08,323] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 172.22.10.21:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:09,724] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (ip-172-22-10-21.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/172.22.10.21:9093) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:09,724] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 172.22.10.21:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-11 19:45:11,149] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (ip-172-22-10-21.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/172.22.10.21:9093) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-512 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: I found that I need to manually add users to make it work. However, I like to know why the broker didn't load user from the jaas file?

   kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server 172.22.10.21:9092 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-512=[iterations=8192,password=adminssl-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name adminssl

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include additional information